# Can you share your artwork in The Looking Glass room without asking for feedback or critique?

Tags: discussion

The bio of the room says: *A room to share your art and **offer feedback**. Everyone is welcome.*

So when you share artwork in Looking Glass, must you need to use phrases like "How is my artwork?", "Is there any scope of improvement?", "Are the colors good?"?

Or you can just share your artwork with just a normal caption like "my new art", but without such questions I mentioned above?

Why I'm asking is: If I just share the artwork without asking questions, I feel I'm using the room as a platform to share artworks, somewhat like Instagram to promote my work, rather than requesting for feedback. Which I'm not sure it is allowed or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you could, but I personally don't think this would be good for the function of the room in the long run. If it were to become a place where every user just dumps artwork to have exposure, it would lose its function as a feedback echo chamber.

A thing to take into account: as far as I know, everything you post onto the SE network, including chat rooms of any kind, will enter into a [copyleft share-alike license](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing). Any images will be uploaded to [imgur](https://imgur.com/) by default, which has its own [licensing shenanigans](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/37658), which may be problematic if you are seeking exposure for commercial work.

Comment: "which may be problematic if you are seeking exposure for commercial work"?

Comment: @Vikas If it turns out that imgur takes ownership of the images you post there, that will create a conflict with the actual copyright holder if you upload any images someone else owns. I haven't read imgur's ToS in full, but the breakdown in the linked answer seems to suggest something like that.

Comment: So for example if I share a final logo designed for a COMPANY, which will have © COMPANY, will also have © imgur and that will become conflicting?

Comment: @Vikas Yes. Thus, don't upload copyrighted material to imgur.

Comment: for my own safety or SE safety?

Comment: @Vikas Your own. Trust me, SE has a good and sharp set of lawyers. /s

Comment: Anyway. "Every user"? LOL there are 2-3 at max.

Comment: Actually, if you link to a external image the chat shows it and sources it form that location. So no igur sharing. But offcourse you must have a webspace somewhere else